# Why is Adobe Configurator 3 not creating a .zxp file when I `File->Export Panel`?

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-creative-suite

I have an InDesign Panel I made with Adobe Configurator 3. I have made modifications and I'm trying to intall the new version in InDesign to try them out. The way I used to do this was to `File->Export Panel` and double-click on the .zxp it creates. But now, for some unknown reason, `Export Panel` doesn't create a .zxp. I don't know what changed since the last time. Any ideas as to why this is the case?

**NOTE**

This is an old question, I since left that job and am no longer in a position to do any testing, nor confirm any new answers.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to my question to make it clearer?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the configurator? This sounds like an application issue. Also have you tried manually giving the file a .zxp extension?

Comment: Can you please tell us if this is on Mac or PC and did you by any chance move your folder with .gpc file?

Comment: @TomEus PC and no, I did not move the folder with the .gpc file.

Comment: OK, so couple of different steps you can try - export to a different location and if that works, copy the content to InDesign, second try running Configurator as administrator (via right click)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an old question, I since left that job and am no longer in a position to do any testing, nor confirm any new answers. That being said, your comments could help someone else visiting for the same reason, so thank you for your efforts anyhow @TomEus

Answer (score 1):

You are using an older version of InDesign.

If you are using Windows Vista -

InDesign 3.0 was released in around April 2007 and if you are using the older Vista, you may be having permissions problems - you cannot save to any location except MyDocuments.

This is so old, your best bet now is to upgrade to latest Windows 7 or Windows 8, use Adobe Cloud InDesign.